# Registered symbol in biblatex bibliography

Tags: biblatex

I am having trouble putting a raised registered symbol (`\textsuperscript{\textregistered}`) in my `biblatex` bibliography.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibencoding=utf8, style=authoryear-icomp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{ref}

\begin{document}

Text\parencite{name}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And the reference:

```
@manual{name,
title = {Title\textsuperscript{\textregistered}},
author = {Some Guy},
year = {2014},
}
```

This produces the following errors:

> ./test.tex:11: Argument of \UTFviii@two@octets has an extra }.
>
> ./test.tex:11: Paragraph ended before \UTFviii@two@octets was complete.
>
> ./test.tex:11: Package inputenc Error: Keyboard character used is undefined

and the bibliography entry shows up without the symbol.

Using either the `\textsuperscript` or `\textregistered` alone does not produce this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get no error; can you tell what TeX distribution you're using?

Comment: Thanks. I am using TeX Live 2013 on OSX Yosemite, all up to date.

Comment: TeX Live is 2014 now.

Comment: Is it 2014 already?;) I'll upgrade and give it a shot. But I'm pretty sure I had the same problem last year, but I just gave up.

Comment: It has been 2014 for several months (from beginning of July).

Comment: Just upgraded to 2014 and it works like a charm. Should have done that first of course, silly me. Any idea what caused this. Cause I'm pretty sure I had the same problem before ( with TexLive 2013 on Ubuntu, about a year ago). Anyway, thank you.

Comment: `biblatex` and `biber` have been updated in the meantime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by an outdated version of `biblatex` and `biber`.

An update to TeX Live 2014 (on Mac OS X it's MacTeX 2014) should solve the issue.

Comment: How can this be solved with something online, like ShareLaTeX or Overleaf?

Comment: @Adam_G Sorry; if they don't upgrade their software…